# ASP.NET CORE 2 disable spell check on input fields using annotations

Tags: asp.net-core, annotations, spell-checking

Using ASP.NET CORE 2, is there a way to disable spell check on input fields using data annotations?  For instance disable spell checking on first name data...
I know about setting spellcheck="false" directly in the html view, but would like to be able to use attributes in the viewmodel / model.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute defines whether the property should spell check:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false)]
public class SpellCheckedAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private bool _spellCheck;
    public SpellCheckedAttribute(bool spellCheck)
    {
        _spellCheck = spellCheck;
    }

    public virtual bool SpellCheck
    {
        get
        {
            return _spellCheck;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in model you can add the attribute on related property :

```
public class YourModel
{
    [SpellChecked(true)]
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

In controller , you can check whether specific property should spell check by :

```
var nameShouldSpellCheck = typeof(YourModel).GetTypeInfo().GetProperty("name").GetCustomAttribute<SpellCheckedAttribute>().SpellCheck;
```

Then you could enable/disable spell check in javscript according to that value .

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to simplify.  I'm sure this would work, but this is a lot more complicated that it needs to be, as opposed to just adding the 'spellcheck="false"' attribute in the views.  I am looking for a solution where all the views will automatically have that attribute set, when the model property is flagged.